# Fundamental Polygon in Python

Tags: python, coordinate-system

I am writing a python class to implement a object moving along a [Fundamental Polygon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_polygon).  It takes in a size of the square and `config` option with three booleans enumerating the 8 possibilities, the first bit indicates whether connected sides are opposite or adjacent, the second indicates if the primary sides are parallel or antiparallel, and the third indicates if the secondary sides are parallel or antiparallel.

For example to denote a torus the `config` would be:

```
 (False, False, False)
```

My implementation of the wraparound (*when the pointer moves off the edge of the square*), is quite messy.  I'm not sure what I should do to make the code more readable and straight forward.

```
class Topology(object):
    def __init__(self,dim,config):
        self.dim = dim
        self.direction = [0,1]
        self.location = [0,0]
        # (matching, primary twist, secondary twist)
        self.config = config
    def move(self):
        self.location = [
            self.location[0]+self.direction[0],
            self.location[1]+self.direction[1]
        ]
        #Important bit
        if self.location[0] >= self.dim[0]:
            if config[1]:
                self.location[1] *= -1
            if config[0]:
                self.location = self.location[::-1]
                self.direction = self.direction[::-1]
        if self.location[1] >= self.dim[1]:
            if config[2]:
                self.location[0] *= -1
            if config[0]:
                self.location = self.location[::-1]
                self.direction = self.direction[::-1]
        if self.location[0] < 0:
            if config[2]:
                self.location[1] *= -1
            if config[0]:
                self.location = self.location[::-1]
                self.direction = self.direction[::-1]
        if self.location[1] < 0:
            if config[1]:
                self.location[0] *= -1
            if config[0]:
                self.location = self.location[::-1]
                self.direction = self.direction[::-1]
        self.location[0] %= self.dim[0]
        self.location[1] %= self.dim[1]
```

Comment: Could you give us and example call to show what a `config` parameter should look like?

Comment: @200_success Sure thing! I added a Torus, as an example.  I limited it to one because I didn't want things to get too crowded,  I could include more if that would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

- First thing first, make `config` a [named tuple](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple). This would seriously improve readability, and obviate the (really unclear) comment.
- Factored out the repeated code into a function, e.g.:

  ```
  def wraparound(coord, matching, twist):
      if 0 < self.location[coord] < self.dimension[coord]:
          return
      if twist:
          self.location[1 - coord] *= -1
      if matching:
          self.location = self.location[::-1]
          self.direction = self.direction[::-1]
  ```

Comment: Thanks! It does look like you forgot to define the `self` variable in your function.

Answer (score 2):

As @vnp said, you can factor out some code, specifically the check on the "matching" part, maybe naming the function with a name explicitly related to what it does.

You can also combine some conditions to make the code a bit more readable.

```
def reverse_if_matching(self, config):
    if config[0]:
        self.location = self.location[::-1]
        self.direction = self.direction[::-1]

def move(self):
    self.location = [
        self.location[0]+self.direction[0],
        self.location[1]+self.direction[1]
    ]

    if self.location[0] >= self.dim[0] and config[1]:
        self.location[1] *= -1
        self.reverse_if_matching(config)

    if self.location[1] >= self.dim[1] and config[2]:
        self.location[0] *= -1
        self.reverse_if_matching(config)

    if self.location[0] < 0 and config[2]:
        self.location[1] *= -1
        self.reverse_if_matching(config)

    if self.location[1] < 0 and config[1]:
        self.location[0] *= -1
        self.reverse_if_matching(config)

    self.location[0] %= self.dim[0]
    self.location[1] %= self.dim[1]
```